# Convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right)^{2n-1}x^n$

Tags: limits, summation, solution-verification

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right)^{2n-1}x^n$ How can I solve this question? I tried Root and Ratio test, but I encounter with $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}$ $\left(\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right)^{\dfrac{-1}{n}}$ so I can't solve this limit, are there anyway to evaluate this limit or sum?

Comment: Do you need to show convergence for certain values of $x$ and/or need the sum of the series? Also, I assume you mean $n\to \infty$ and not $x\to \infty$.

Comment: The root test will work just fine.

Comment: Actually what values of x to this series will be converge

Comment: Yeah I tried it and I make it, I can see $|x|<4$but I can't solve the limit I mentioned in the question, I just intuitvely see...

Comment: Each term is about $\frac x4$ times the previous term.  Hence your $|x|<4$

Comment: No, in the root test I get the term that I mentioned above

Comment: I tried again, I think I'm not going to be Mathematician :D

Comment: Your root test should look like $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n\left(\frac n{2n+1}\right)^{2n-1}}$$ is this what you used?

Comment: Yes that's what I used. But I couldn't make it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the root test, we have

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|x^n\left(\frac n{2n+1}\right)^{2n-1}\right|}\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty} |x|\left|\frac n{2n+1}\right|^{\frac{2n-1}n}\\
=|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac 12-\frac1{4n+2}\right|^{2-\frac 1n}\\
=|x|\left(\frac 12\right)^2\\
=\frac {|x|}4$$

Comment: Did you neglect the $\left(\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right)^{\dfrac{-1}{n}}$?

Comment: @beingmathematician: no, but I glossed over it.  Please see my edit.

Comment: I see now, thanks a lot! It's perfect!

Comment: I guess you also want to take the absolute value at some places :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: good call, added that in

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test works nice. Let
$$a_n=\left(\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right)^{2n-1}\implies \log(a_n)=(2n-1)\log\left(\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right)$$ By Taylor
$$\log\left(\dfrac{n}{2n+1}\right)=-\log (2)-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{8 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\log(a_n)=-2 n \log (2)+(\log (2)-1)+\frac{3}{4 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Apply it twice and continue with long division
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=-2 \log (2)-\frac{3}{4 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1} }{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{16 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: I like it! Thanks a lot! If I let to use Taylor by instructor, I will use this.